# Bernoulli estimator bias

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, estimators, bernoulli-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim Bernoulli(p)$, where $n > 5$. Let $\hat p = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{5} X_i$ be the estimator of $p$. Is it biased?

My guess is no, since $E[\hat p] =  \frac{1}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{5} E[X_i] = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{5} p = \frac{5p}{5} = p$.

However, I find this counterintuitive. If I flip a fair coin 5 times to compute the estimator and happen to get heads ($X_i = 0$) every time, then $\hat p = 0$, but the real $p$ is $0.5$, so I am underestimating the parameter $p$.

Comment: *No matter* what is your estimator, you can always find for it such data that it won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unbiased does not mean that you estimate the parameter correctly in each and every sample, it means that the errors you make in any particular samples tend to average eachother away across many independent samples.

In your case, every sample in which you flip no heads is matched by an equally likely sample where you flip no tails.  In the long run you would get about as many no heads samples as no tails, so the number of heads across all such samples averages to 2.5, and the proportion of heads in such samples averages out to $\frac{2.5}{5} = 0.5$

> This is then an example of an unbiased but inconsistent estimator.

It's consistent.  Your estimator $\hat p$ is a sample mean, and you can calculate the variance of a sample mean quite easily (as long as the flips are independent)

$$ var(\hat p) = \frac{5p(1 - p)}{n} $$

As your sample get's larger, $n \rightarrow \infty$, and so $var(\hat p) \rightarrow 0$.  Using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) immediately implies that the estimator is consistent.

Comment: Nice. I had the wrong intuition. This is then an example of an unbiased but inconsistent estimator.

Comment: It's also a consistent estimator.  Added a discussion to the answer.

Comment: Oops. My variance is wrong: $var(\hat p) = var(\frac{1}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{5} X_i) = \frac{1}{5^2} \sum_{i=1}^{5} var(X_i) = \frac{1}{5^2} \sum_{i=1}^{5} p(1-p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{5}$. Why?

Comment: Is it because I should consider all of the $n$ trials? @MatthewDrury

Comment: I'm also unsure why @Amanjo's variance is wrong there. do you have a slightly more explicit derivation you could share?

Comment: @Amanjo's variance calculation is correct, the original question says to use the first five draws, not all n draws. moreover, the estimator is not consistent. The original question says that there are n>5 draws, but only the first five are used to construct the estimator. Therefore larger n does not reduce the (repeat-sample) variance of the estimator, hence it is inconsistent.